# Translating "What I said still holds"

Tags: traducción

The best way I can think of to phrase this is "Lo que dije todavía vale", but it feels to me this is too much of a literal translation. Would there be a better alternative? Thank you.

Comment: No, it's fine. Really.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your translation is valid, but you could also say:

- *Mantengo lo que dije*
- *Lo que dije sigue en pie*

Answer (score 2):

Otras validas;

- Sostengo lo que dije.
- Lo que dije lo mantengo.
- Lo que dije sigue vigente.
- Lo que dije aún esta vigente.
- Lo que dije continua en vigor.
- Lo que dije aún tiene vigor.
- Lo que dije aún es válido.
- Lo que dije aún esta presente.
- Lo que dije aún esta reinante.
- Lo que dije se mantiene en pie.
- Mantengo vivo lo que dije.
- Lo que dije aún es efectivo.
- Lo que dije aún rige.

Comment: Some of those are not the same register as the question. El inglés es mas bien informal.

Comment: La pregunta que aparece como base en el desarrollo, "Lo que dije todavía vale", esta formulada en Español y no en Inglés, "What I said still holds", que sí aparece en el título, por tanto, no todas las respuestas que se dan en Español van a tener en cuenta las posibles peculiaridades que éstas mismas tienen cuando se formulan o se expresan en Inglés. De hecho en Español, también pueden incluir distintas connotaciones que varían según el contexto y el nivel cultural del que se expresa, en ese sentido simplemente, he intentado abrir el abanico de posibilidades. Gracias.